# SSRS How to add multiple grouping horizontally

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

Hi I am total noob to SSRS but somehow got a task to create reports. My current issue is that I need grouping like in image. Can anyone please help me to add groups like this one.

[image]

I have followed this tutorial :
http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2010/3/31/ssrs-multiple-row-grouping-elements-to-appear-under-a-single-column-within-a-table-in-a-report

But whenever I add groups or subgroups mentioned in the tutorial, These groups and subgroups gets inserted at the beginning of report.

Do some one have detailed tutorial or video?

Here is what going on at my end:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "at the beginning of report"? Isn't "Geo Group" in your example at the beginning as well?

Comment: This image is just for example. I have not created it I mean when following tutorial whenever I add new sub group it gets inserted at the beginning of report

I have edited question.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by at the beginning. The very definition of grouping data is that the group information has to be displayed first. What else do you want to see first if not the group column? Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677373(v=sql.100).aspx for a overview about grouping.

Comment: I like output like this: http://imgur.com/PDCIGZL

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add a group after an existing group:

1. select the existing group (either in the `tablix` or in the *Row Groups* area)
2. right click -> *Add Group* -> *Child Group...*

[image]